# Terminal issue with rspec

Tags: ruby, terminal, rspec

I have just setup rspec on my terminal with the following commands:

`gem install rspec`

`rspec --init`

The last command gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    15: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    14: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    13: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    12: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    11: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
     9: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     8: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `new'
     7: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:14:in `initialize'
     6: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:47:in `organize_options'
     5: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:125:in `file_options'
     4: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:151:in `project_options'
     3: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:159:in `options_from'
     2: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:171:in `args_from_options_file'
     1: from /Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:179:in `options_file_as_erb_string'
/Users/anouarldn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:179:in `read': Is a directory @ io_fread - ./.rspec (Errno::EISDIR)
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: `Errno::EISDIR` means that it's expecting to read a file but it found a directory. Looks like there's something wrong with your Rspec install or something else in your local configuration.

Comment: rspec is storing some config in a local file `.rspec`, and it looks like you already have a directory with that name, check it out. (It's local in your project)